# How to get gcc to not warn about issues in some "external headers" but include those headers as dependencies?

Tags: gcc, header-files, gcc-warning, external-dependencies

It is almost impossible to try increasing the warning level, or using -Werror when working in a large project with many groups developing smaller pieces, and maintaining large amount of legacy code: there are always too many warnings coming from some headers that belong to some other groups that render the whole thing unusable.

The [bad] workaround everybody seems to be abusing is to replace the -I headers search path option with -isystem for all the headers that are in the project, but belong to "some other groups"... This is bad because, while it avoids getting lost in warnings from those "external-headers", that also exclude those from the dependency file generated by gcc, which can lead the build system to not know what to recompile when some project header is updated.

Using gcc/g++, is there a way to do all of the following at once:

- exclude true system headers both from reporting warnings and from being included in dependency generation;
- exclude some project headers from specific directories from reporting warning, but still include them in the dependency generation;
- for all other header: both report warning and include them in the dependency generation;

all while generating the dependency file and building the object file for a given source C/C++ file in one single command?

Comment: Are you compiling and generating dependencies in a single compiler invocation? Quite often people do it in 2 separate steps, which would allow using -I for one and -isystem for the other.

Comment: Yes... One command saves a lot of build time... But of course if it is the only option to solve that at the command level, we may have to re-evaluate that :(
It would be great if gcc had an option for that (it seems like an inefficient hack to use -isystem + 2 separate commands to get to that result).